# How to pass a parameter to Scikit-Learn Keras model function

Tags: python, function, scikit-learn, keras, callable

I have the following code, using [Keras Scikit-Learn Wrapper](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/wrappers/scikit_learn.py), which work fine:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from sklearn import datasets
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
import numpy as np


def create_model():
    # create model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(12, input_dim=4, init='uniform', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(6, init='uniform', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1, init='uniform', activation='sigmoid'))
    # Compile model
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model


def main():
    """
    Description of main
    """


    iris = datasets.load_iris()
    X, y = iris.data, iris.target

    NOF_ROW, NOF_COL =  X.shape

    # evaluate using 10-fold cross validation
    seed = 7
    np.random.seed(seed)
    model = KerasClassifier(build_fn=create_model, nb_epoch=150, batch_size=10, verbose=0)
    kfold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True, random_state=seed)
    results = cross_val_score(model, X, y, cv=kfold)

    print(results.mean())
    # 0.666666666667


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The `pima-indians-diabetes.data`  can be downloaded **[here](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/pima-indians-diabetes/pima-indians-diabetes.data)**.

Now what I want to do is to pass a value `NOF_COL` into a parameter of `create_model()` function the following way

```
model = KerasClassifier(build_fn=create_model(input_dim=NOF_COL), nb_epoch=150, batch_size=10, verbose=0)
```

With the `create_model()` function that looks like this:

```
def create_model(input_dim=None):
    # create model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(12, input_dim=input_dim, init='uniform', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(6, init='uniform', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1, init='uniform', activation='sigmoid'))
    # Compile model
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model
```

But it fails giving this error:

```
TypeError: __call__() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)
```

What's the right way to do it?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can add an `input_dim` keyword argument to the `KerasClassifier` constructor:

```
model = KerasClassifier(build_fn=create_model, input_dim=5, nb_epoch=150, batch_size=10, verbose=0)
```

Answer (score 10):

Last answer does not work anymore.

An alternative is to return a function from create_model, as KerasClassifier build_fn expects a function:

```
def create_model(input_dim=None):
    def model():
        # create model
        nn = Sequential()
        nn.add(Dense(12, input_dim=input_dim, init='uniform', activation='relu'))
        nn.add(Dense(6, init='uniform', activation='relu'))
        nn.add(Dense(1, init='uniform', activation='sigmoid'))
        # Compile model
        nn.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
        return nn

    return model
```

Or even better, according to [documentation](https://keras.io/scikit-learn-api/#wrappers-for-the-scikit-learn-api)

> sk_params takes both model parameters and fitting parameters. Legal model parameters are the arguments of build_fn. Note that like all other estimators in scikit-learn, build_fn should provide *default values* for its arguments, so that you could create the estimator without passing any values to sk_params

So you can define your function like this:

```
def create_model(number_of_features=10): # 10 is the *default value*
    # create model
    nn = Sequential()
    nn.add(Dense(12, input_dim=number_of_features, init='uniform', activation='relu'))
    nn.add(Dense(6, init='uniform', activation='relu'))
    nn.add(Dense(1, init='uniform', activation='sigmoid'))
    # Compile model
    nn.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return nn
```

And create a wrapper:

```
KerasClassifier(build_fn=create_model, number_of_features=20, epochs=25, batch_size=1000, ...)
```

Answer (score 1):

To pass a parameter to build_fn model, can be done passing arguments to `__init__()` and in turn it will be passed to `model_build_fn` directly. For example, calling `KerasClassifier(myparam=10)` will result in a `model_build_fn(my_param=10)`

here's an example:

```
class MyMultiOutputKerasRegressor(KerasRegressor):
    
    # initializing
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        KerasRegressor.__init__(self, **kwargs)
        
    # simpler fit method
    def fit(self, X, y, **kwargs):
        KerasRegressor.fit(self, X, [y]*3, **kwargs)
```

(...)

```
def get_quantile_reg_rpf_nn(layers_shape=[50,100,200,100,50], inDim= 4, outDim=1, act='relu'):
          # do model stuff...
```

(...)
initialize the Keras regressor:

```
base_model = MyMultiOutputKerasRegressor(build_fn=get_quantile_reg_rpf_nn,
                                         layers_shape=[50,100,200,100,50], inDim= 4, 
                                         outDim=1, act='relu', epochs=numEpochs, 
                                         batch_size=batch_size, verbose=0)
```