# How to perform KerasClassifier model selection with varying input dimensions

Tags: python, scikit-learn, keras

I am trying to perform model selection on a KerasClassifier, for several sliding windows of samples. However, each sliding window has a different input dimension (as a result of feature selection).

The function I have written works for regular scikit-learn classifiers. i.e. it returns a dictionary containing optimal RF models (using random grid search):

```
# return a dictionary with optimal models for each sliding window
rf_optimal_models = model_selection(RandomForestClassifier(), 
param_distributions = random_grid_rf, n_iter = 10)
```

However, I am unsure how to set up the KerasClassifier in such a way that it will change the input_dim argument according to the dimensions of the sliding window being passed to it.

The following code sets up the keras scikit-learn wrapper.

```
def create_model(optimizer='adam', kernel_initializer='normal', dropout_rate=0.0):
    with tf.device("/device:GPU:0"):
        # create model
        model = Sequential()
        model.add(Dense(20, input_dim=X_train.shape[1], activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer))
        model.add(Dropout(dropout_rate))
        model.add(Dense(20, activation='relu'))
        model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
        # Compile model
        model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])
        return model
```

... and the call to my model_selection() function.

```
mlp_optimal_models =  model_selection(model = KerasClassifier(build_fn=create_model, verbose=0,), param_distributions = random_grid_mlp, n_iter = 10)
```

The input_dim argument is static and will throw an error when it receives dimensions of say 49 (the input dim of the next sliding window), but expects 42.

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_1_input to have shape 
(42,) but got array with shape (49,)
```

The code below is a simplified version of my model_selection() function:

```
def model_selection(model, param_distributions, n_iter = 100):
    """
    This function performs model selection using random grid search *without cross validation*.
    Inputs:
        model: enter model such as RandomForestClassifier() (which is default)
        param_distributions: pre-defined grid to search over, specific to the input 'model'
        n_iter: Number of parameter settings that are sampled. n_iter trades off runtime vs quality of the solution.
    """

    # dictionary to hold optimal models for each sliding window
    optimal_models = {}

    # 'sets' is a dictionary containing sliding window dataframes e.g. 'X_train_0', 'y_train_0', 'X_test_0', 'y_test_0', 'X_train_1', 'y_train_1', 'X_test_1', 'y_test_1'

    for i in np.arange(0, len(sets), 4): # for each sliding window

            # assign the train and validation sets for the given sliding window
            X_train = list(sets_for_model_selection.values())[i] # THESE HAVE DIFFERENT DIMS FROM WINDOW TO WINDOW
            X_val = list(sets_for_model_selection.values())[i+1] # THESE HAVE DIFFERENT DIMS FROM WINDOW TO WINDOW
            y_train = list(sets_for_model_selection.values())[i+2]
            y_val = list(sets_for_model_selection.values())[i+3]

            # set up the grid search
            mdl_opt = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator = model, param_distributions = param_distributions, 
                                 n_iter = n_iter, cv = ps, verbose=2)

            # Fit the random search model: parameter combinations will be trained, then tested on the validation set
            mdl_opt.fit(np.concatenate((X_train, X_val), axis = 0), 
                np.concatenate((y_train.values.ravel(), y_val.values.ravel()), axis = 0))

            mdl = {'optimal_model_sw'+str(i) : mdl_opt.best_estimator_}

            # update the 'optimal models' dictionary
            optimal_models.update(mdl)

return optimal_models
```

Comment: Maybe this can help:https://stackoverflow.com/q/40393629/3374996

Comment: Thank you. That got me part of the way there. I will outline how it was used in an answer.

Answer (score 2):

The solution involved a slight edit to the KerasClassifier wrapper and an editing my function `model_selection()`.

First I changed the `input_dim` to 'None':

```
def create_model(optimizer='adam', kernel_initializer='normal', dropout_rate=0.0, input_dim=None):
    with tf.device("/device:GPU:0"):
        # create model
        model = Sequential()
        model.add(Dense(20, input_dim=None, activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer))
        model.add(Dropout(dropout_rate))
        model.add(Dense(20, activation='relu'))
        model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
        # Compile model
        model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])
        return model
```

Then within the model selection function I added an extra argument 'mlp' to assert whether the model in question was a neural network.

If True, the `KerasClassifier` model is created within the `model_selection()` function where it has access to the number of dimensions for the sliding window in question. These are used as inputs to the `input_dim` keyarg in the `KerasClassifier` constructor (as in the link Vivek Kumar pointed out):

```
def model_selection(model, param_distributions, n_iter = 100, mlp=None):
    """
    This function performs model selection using random grid search *without cross validation*.
    Inputs:
        model: enter model such as RandomForestClassifier() (which is default)
        param_distributions: pre-defined grid to search over, specific to the input 'model'
        n_iter: Number of parameter settings that are sampled. n_iter trades off runtime vs quality of the solution.
    """
    # dictionary to hold optimal models for each sliding window
    optimal_models = {}

# 'sets' is a dictionary containing sliding window dataframes e.g. 'X_train_0', 'y_train_0', 'X_test_0', 'y_test_0', 'X_train_1', 'y_train_1', 'X_test_1', 'y_test_1'

    for i in np.arange(0, len(sets), 4): # for each sliding window

        # assign the train and validation sets for the given sliding window
        X_train = list(sets_for_model_selection.values())[i] # THESE HAVE DIFFERENT DIMS FROM WINDOW TO WINDOW
        X_val = list(sets_for_model_selection.values())[i+1] # THESE HAVE DIFFERENT DIMS FROM WINDOW TO WINDOW
        y_train = list(sets_for_model_selection.values())[i+2]
        y_val = list(sets_for_model_selection.values())[i+3]

        if mlp:
            input_dims = list(sets_for_model_selection.values())[i].shape[1]
            model =  KerasClassifier(build_fn=create_model, input_dim=input_dims, verbose=0)

        # set up the grid search
        mdl_opt = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator = model, param_distributions = param_distributions, 
                             n_iter = n_iter, cv = ps, verbose=2)

        # Fit the random search model: parameter combinations will be trained, then tested on the validation set
        mdl_opt.fit(np.concatenate((X_train, X_val), axis = 0), 
            np.concatenate((y_train.values.ravel(), y_val.values.ravel()), axis = 0))

        mdl = {'optimal_model_sw'+str(i) : mdl_opt.best_estimator_}

        # update the 'optimal models' dictionary
        optimal_models.update(mdl)
    return optimal_models
```